# Job match email: Location issue

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I've just received a job match email which I tend to get on a daily basis; but for some reason the location is *way* off - as in different country kind of off. I'm based in the United Kingdom, but these roles are listed as being in MA.

[image: Screengrab of email outlining issue]

Furthermore, none of these [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/156266/lead-architect-to-shape-tech-stack-at-edtech-vemo-education) are actually in Holyoke, MA - but instead seem to be based in New York.

Comment: Same here, i created a Job Alert for Grand Rapids, Michigan and Lansing, Michigan, each with +100 KM.  On December 5th i got a Email advertising Jobs in Holyoke, MA, wich is over 1000 KM away. Factor ten issue like in Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis???